# What is this Russian word which means "just a sec"?

Tags: перевод

I am looking for a word I heard already several Russian people say and that yet I can’t find on any translation platform. This word sounded like «час», or «счас», in the context of «give me a sec», or «one moment please».

But I have no clue how to write this word and what it is supposed to accurately mean by itself. Could someone please help me? ^^ )

Comment: "секунду !", "подожди секунду !"

Answer (score 25):

Most common variants are "сейчас" (which colloquially is pronounced "сщас" or "щас"), "[одну] секунду / секундочку", "[одну] минуту / минуточку" and "[один] момент".

If one wants to put emphasis on what more or less corresponds to "just" in "just a sec", they can say something like "буквально секунду".

Comment: Ah, now I know what my wife is saying whenever I need her for a moment when she's on the phone, and she needs to tell the person on the other end to hold on a second. It's сейчас.

Comment: @hobbs Your wife is Russian and you don't speak the language? You are brave...

Comment: still, a brave man can be adored for it!

Comment: @fraxinus Ukrainian (but she speaks Russian, especially among the expat crowd here in the US). I understand some but I'm notwhere near conversational.

Comment: Colloquially it's even sometimes "ща" XD

Answer (score 18):

You're probably looking for *щас* which is just a lenient rendition of *сейчас*.

It's the same as saying "wassup" instead of "what's up" or "ain't" instead of "am not" or "have not" in English.

*Сейчас* is often used in Russian in the sense of "a moment" (like in "give me a moment").

In writing, it's usually rendered as *сейчас*, unless you want to emphasize the leniency with [eye spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect). In the latter case, it's written as *щас* or *счас*

Comment: and the most lazy form of it, "Ща!"

Answer (score 6):

We (Russian speakers) quite often say: "пять сек" (5 sec) in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

I uses 'минуту' which stands for 'Подождите одну минуту' 'Wait for a minute' or 'секунду' if pause is very short (about a few seconds)